# MVC3 "Dynamic" Parameter List Model and View

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

Need a hand/guide of creating a view that handles a list of parameters which we get the name of during run time, currently during the postback it just won't return anything, using the MVC html helpers.

My Models

```
public class Parameter {
  public string Name {get; set;}
  public string Value {get; set;}
}  

public class Job {
  public List<Parameter> parameters {get; set;}
}
```

My Views

Add View

```
@model Models.Job
@using (Html.BeginForm("Add","Job")) {
  @foreach (var parameter in Model.Parameters)
  {
    @Html.Action("AddParameter","Job", parameter)
  }
 </fieldset>
}
```

AddParameter View

```
@model Models.Parameter

<div class="editor-label">
    <label for="@Model.Name">@Model.Name</label>
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Value)
</div>
```

when this get's posted back to the below controller the list is not populated. I think i'm probably going about it in completely the wrong way but no idea how to really implement it. It seems the "dynamic" parameter concept is the thing really throwing me. Will this approach work and i've just got some things wrong? or do i need to look at another way of doing it?

Controller

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Add(Job model)
{
    //Do Something
    return PartialView();
}
```

Comment: where is your Action method for AddParameter view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is related to returning a List from the view... check this post by Phil Haack:

[Model Binding To A List](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx)

Here you can see I ran into the same problem. The solution proposed guided me in the right direction but it wasn't the one I used, I used Phil's post.

[My Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6765424/return-a-liste-from-a-view-in-view-model)

Hope this helps...

EDIT: To clarify, what you need to do is change your AddParameter View into an EditorTemplate and use it as instructed in the above post by Phil.

Comment: Thanks! The link to your question helped me solve this. First time using the custom Editor Templates, so learnt something new and helpful as well!

Comment: @ct5845 Glad I copuld help, It was my first Editor Template as well.