# Edit View for the model that contains the List <T> where T some another class

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, list, editview

It seems I'm tangled up in broad daylight:

I have a model classes

```
public class Pilot
{
    //.. other prop-s escaped
    private List<FlightHoursEntry> FlightHours { get; set; }
}

public class FlightHoursEntry
{
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public int Hours { get; set; }
}
```

Views are listed bleow, all is displayed correctly, but **on postback FlightHours property is null, Why the engine doesn't initialize the Pilot's object correctly?**

in the PilotEditView I'm using *@Html.EditorFor(model => model.FlightHours)*

FlightHoursCollectionView is:

```
@model List<FlightHoursEntry>

@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++){
FlightHoursEntry fh = Model[i];
@Html.Partial("~/../FlightHoursEntryEditView.cshtml", fh);}
```

also I've tried this way
    @Html.EditorFor(model=>model[i], "FlightHoursEntryEditView", fh)

and the simple FlightHoursEntryEditView

```
@model PumaMvc.Models.BusinessObjects.Copa.FlightHoursEntry

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Hours)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Hours)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Hours)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Description)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">      
        @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Description)           
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Description)
    </div>
```

Comment: You don't need the @ symbol in the second code segment before `Html.Partial(..` because you are already in a C# context

Answer (score 0):

The filed is marked `private`. I suspect the field needs to be public for the MVC ModelBinder to Bind incoming values to it.

**EDIT :**

If the above does not work :

Also check this out : http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx
Phil blogs about how to modelbind to a list of complex objects, you will need to change the editor for FlightHoursEntry class to reflect as it is shown over there. Simply render the value of `i` within square braces in the final HTML.

There is also an example there, but the post is a little bit out of date, and has MVC2 being used everywhere.

Comment: Let me know, if access modifier private is the cause or not, thanks.

Comment: no, in real code it's public property, mistake only in the post. thanks for the article will read.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the following post. Really helped me on my way to understanding how to implement this 
- [Return a List<E> from a view in view model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6765424/return-a-liste-from-a-view-in-view-model)