# ListBox and ajax in ASP.NET mvc3

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3, listbox

i have two Listboxes in mvc3
the first one have all products and the other is empty
i want to select some products from the first Listbox to the empty list box using Ajax
and when the user click the save button insert the selected items (in the second Listbox)
th database

i used this example http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/Mvc2ListBox.aspx
but i can convert the submit add to Ajax add
the big problem with me the index action have model parameter but the javascript can not see the model object

plz help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem is related to this question I made regarding returning a List from the view to the controller:

[Return a List<E> from a view in view model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6765424/return-a-liste-from-a-view-in-view-model)

Also look at this link which helped me a great deal to solve it:

http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx

Hope this helps, If I missundertud your problem, let me know so we can find another answer.

Comment: No 
i want to know how i can edit the model using ajax without submit